# Free VPN and bank password security

Tags: passwords, vpn

For some odd reason my online banking fails when on mobile data. It works fine on wifi. In times past I used nokia's Xpress browser to route it through their servers but it is no longer available for use.

My idea is to use one of the free VPN services out there to route my traffic through but I was wondering how secure is that? I know that there should be SSL involved but seeing as I am on mobile IE I am still kinda leery seeing as I dont know that i have an easy way to see any ssl certs involved.

The other option I have is to set my own personal vpn on a digital ocean VPS I have but that looks to be quite a bit more work.

Also seeing as I am on windows phone 8.1 I am limited to IKEv2 or L2TP with IPSec. Are there any free services I could use that support those and y'all could recommend? Or should I just go the hard route and set my own up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using VPN may secure the connection between your device and vpn server but its not enough. Not using vpn may be more secure than using a public one, you shouldn't trust a unknown machine.

Building your own VPN server on a droplet is something you can try. I'm using SoftEther VPN Server for that and I can suggest that to you. It has a nice GUI administrating panel for Windows, after installing it to a droplet you can use graphical interface to manage it simply. It also supports many protocols, nearly all of them! You can connect it via OpenVPN, L2TP with IPsec, SSTP etc. It also has its own client that supports ICMP & DNS hole punching and VPN over SSL that allows you to connect from vpn-restricted networks with high speed.

Digital Ocean Community has a tutorial for setup:
[How to Setup a Multi-Protocol VPN Server Using SoftEther](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-multi-protocol-vpn-server-using-softether)

By the way: If you use DigitalOcean to build your own VPN server, after everything is done you can take a snapshot of your droplet and destroy your droplet. Whenever you need some security, all you need to do is creating a droplet from existing snapshot, the snapshot that you took last time. IP address of server may change but the server will stay up and running. By doing this you only pay for hours that you actually use.